# reproducing solidity address() in python

Tags: solidity, python

the below solidity code converts 29144403828894911802891993729705329970730667872118118  to 0x690a87Ed8972e451e755b8F2dC1fc2B28e3c6566

I would like to reproduce this in python but have come up short. Can anyone point me in the right direction. or give me an idea of what the address() function is doing?

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

contract Simple {

    function getAddress(uint256 p) public  returns (address) {
        address pool = address(p);
        return pool;
    }
}
```

Comment: address(p) is equivalent to address(uint160(p)), it trims the 256 bits number to 160 bits and returns it as address

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

solved it

```
'0x' +Web3.to_hex(29144403828894911802891993729705329970730667872118118)[-40:]
```